# Expanding list from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make list expand from bottom to top. It works, but if the list is too big, it goes over the "top" div. My idea is when the list is too big, I will have scroll bar and "bottom" div to have like 50% of "top" div. I can't make it top: 0 because If I do it, the div goes up. Same as for using height on "bottom". I know why is not working now, but I have no more ideas how to fix it. Any ideas would be helpful.

https://plnkr.co/edit/0qZVy8PeZ6uUwejV1AFf?p=preview

```
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just gone through your provided link. Add these properties to **.bottom**

```
max-height:300px;
overflow-y:auto;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so so much

Comment: Np :)
Just up vote it and mark it as answer xD
@Erad

Answer (score 0):

Take `position: absolute;` off of .bottom and then add `overflow-y: scroll;` to .top